# How to order data according to a huge custom list?

Tags: excel, sorting

So, I'm trying to sort a huge table (several hundred lines and columns) with a catch: I need to sort them according to the list of names I have in a column. Yes, I know I could sort them in many different ways easily, but for what I'm doing, it is imperative to follow this specific order. Any tips or tricks on how to sort this out would be most welcome!

Comment: I don't understand why someone would downvote a perfectly legitimate question! Was it because I kept Googling and found it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer!

1.Select the range of data that is going to be your 'custom list'.

2.Then go to File > Options > Advanced

3. In the Advanced tab, search for the General section. In there, you'll find a "Edit Custom Lists..."
4. A query will pop up, and there will be, on the bottom, a small textbox with your range, next to a 'Import' button! Click on 'Import'!

And it creates your custom list!

(Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sort-data-using-a-custom-list-cba3d67a-c5cb-406f-9b14-a02205834d72)